# WCF Rest GET returns nothing when I use virtual properties

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

It's my first time developing a Rest WCF service.

This is what I did to get all users in database:

```
namespace MyCompanyWCFService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyCompanyService
    {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/users",
                BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract]
        List<User> GetAllUsers();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        MyClass DoWork();
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
namespace MyCompanyWCFService
{
    public class MyCompanyService : IMyCompanyService
    {
        public List<User> GetAllUsers()
        {
            List<User> usersList = null;

            using (var context = new MyCompanyContext())
            {
                usersList = context.Users.ToList();
            }

            return usersList;
        }

        public MyClass DoWork()
        {
            var returnObject = new MyClass
            {
                Id = 1,
                IHaveNoDataMemberAttribute = "Meaningless",
                Name = "Satchmo",
                NoPublicGet = "Hello world!",
                InternalProperty = 155
            };
            return returnObject;
        }
    }
}
```

`User` model class:

```
namespace MyCompanyModel
{
    [DataContract]
    public class User
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int Age { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string InterestIn { get; set; }


        [DataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<User> Friends { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<User> FromWhomIsFriend { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<Activity> WantsToDo { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<Message> MessagesSent { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<Message> MessagesReceived { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string output = string.Empty;

            output = String.Format("UserId: {0}, Name: {1}, Age: {2}, City: {3}, " +
                "Country: {4}, Email: {5}, InterestIn: {6}",
                UserId, Name, Age, City, Country, Email, InterestIn);

            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

`MyClass`:

```
namespace MyCompanyWCFService
{
    [DataContract]
    public class MyClass
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string IHaveNoDataMemberAttribute { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string NoPublicGet { private get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        internal ushort InternalProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework"
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
             requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyCompanyWCFService.MyCompanyService">
        <endpoint address="" 
                  contract="MyCompanyWCFService.IMyCompanyService"
                  behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior"
                  bindingConfiguration=""
                  binding="webHttpBinding" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyCompanyContext"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
          connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyCompany;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

But, when I set this URI, `http://localhost:7342/MyCompanyService.svc/users`, on my web browser I get nothing. I have also test it with PostMan Chrome extension and I get nothing.

Debugging the code `context.Users.ToList();` returns three users.

But, it I do, `http://localhost:7342/MyCompanyService.svc/DoWork`, it works perfectly:

`{"Id":1,"InternalProperty":155,"Name":"Satchmo","NoPublicGet":"Hello world!"}`

The problem is with `public virtual` properties. If I remove `virtual`, it works but I need `virtual` to lazy load on these navigation properties.

**How can I solve this problem?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed the error doing this `context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` here:

```
    public List<User> GetAllUsers()
    {
        List<User> usersList = null;

        using (var context = new AdnLineContext())
        {
            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            usersList = context.Users.ToList();
        }

        return usersList;
    }
```